# Is there a way to prevent the addon menu from being hidden when a Google Document is locked?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

I want to write an Add-on for Google Documents that creates a drop-down menu, with several commands, one of which locks the document. I can do that. But once the user locks the document, the add-on menu is hidden (along with several of the built-in options) and doesn't come back until the document is unlocked.

Is there any way to change this behavior?

Comment: Can you specify in what way you lock the document?

Comment: Yep, using URLFetchApp to call the Drive V3 API. Passing

 var contentRestrictions = [
                              { 
                                readOnly: true,
                                reason: 'Prevent editing',
                              }
  ];

Comment: Once you lock the document it is not editible anymore and thus neither a script nor an Add-on menu will be accessible anymore - just like as if you have view-only permissions.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I guessed that was the case, but that seems to me to be a failure of imagination on Google's part. The contents aren't editable, but editing isn't the only thing you can do to a  document, or might want to do to it with an add-on, or might want to do to something else in the context of the document.